# how to resolve 2nd level dependencies using maven

Tags: java, maven

I have project A which a pom.xml dependency of:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jolbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>bonecp-spring</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran mvn install to install projectA.jar into the local maven repo.

In project B, i depend projectA.jar

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>projectA</groupId>
    <artifactId>projectA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

When I run project B, it fails due to a missing class file:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Error loading class [com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong. How to include second level dependencies?
Thanks.

Comment: did you run maven again after including project A in the project B pom.xml? Were there any errors in the maven logs?

Comment: what is your maven version? transitive dependencies are only support in 2.0.

Comment: This is what  do normally:
1. I create project A
2. install it into local mvn repository
3. Include project A into pom.xml of project B
4. execute 'mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse' on project B
5. execute 'mvn clean package' on project B
6. Deploy project B(war) in JBOSS

While deploying I get error:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource

I get the same error, when I try to execute JUnit test in Project B.


I am using Apache Maven 3.1.1

Comment: One of my colleagues suggested to include all pom dependencies from project A to project B. But, I am not convinced.

Comment: try to run mvn eclipse:clean and mvn eclipse:eclipse separately. Then don't do mvn clean package afterwards..

Comment: also what is the in the maven logs after you run mvn eclipse:eclipse? Are there any errors?

Comment: In your war can you see `bonecp-spring-0.7.1-RELEASE.jar` in the WEB-INF/lib?

Comment: @user1928162, if I don't do 'mvn clean package', how am I supposed to create the war file to deploy it in JBOSS?

Comment: I do not get any error after 'mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse'

Comment: @Will Keeling, I don't see `bonecp-spring-0.7.1-RELEASE.jar` in WEB-INF/lib. When I add the dependencies required for project A, inside project B -> pom.xml, I see this jar.